# How to Manage API Authentication Lifecycle on Mobile Devices? Magento2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, oauth

> Every hour **regeneration** of token and after that login again every hour
>   is not logical for **Mobile Application.**
>
> Then how Magento manages user login data and authentication in Mobile
>   application, if it is developed API As per Service Contracts

- How long should I allow my **access tokens** to **exist** before
  expiring them in Mobile Application?
- I don’t want to force my users to **re-authenticate** every hour in Mobile Application.
- how to properly manage your **OAuth2** API token life-cycle for Mobile Application.

Making changes in **Access Token Lifetime hours** would not be logical solution, Because Application and web should have different lifetime hours of Token

[image]